# How to index e-commerce site using javascript only

Tags: javascript, python, json, loops, e-commerce

How would you index an e-commerce site using front-end (javascript) only?

All products are on one URL, showing 12 per page and has about 70 in total. There are also filters, filter data need to be collected as well (in which category a product belongs, could be multiple).

Products update using Ajax, site uses Angular

A result should be JSON.

Formula I am using now:

- Activate one filter
- Wait till products appear
- Create an object for product (if it already does not exist)
- Push values to created object (name, price, img, url, color(category) ...)
- Loop through all visible products
- Disable filter
- Activate another filter
- repeat until done

Also should add logic for looping through all pages on each filter.

Example result:

```
{  
      "objectID":1,
      "title":"Apple Slice Ring Candle",
      "price":24.95,
      "url":"/products/apple-slice-ring-candle",
      "imgurl":"//image-cdn.symphonycommerce.com/images/sites/diamondcandles/1411480495935_apple-slice-Web-Optimized.312w.jpg",
      "color":"green",
      "fragrance":[
        "fruity"
      ],
      "ambience":"focused"
}
```

Page I am talking about: https://www.diamondcandles.com/ring-candles

Could also use Python, or any other tool - only condition is I can't access their backend, database etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the best answer I could think of is:

- Load all products into one page, using iframe and jquery
- Index these products and collect information such as: price, image, url, description
- Activate first filter, then loop through visible products and products in my list - ones that match should get that category added.
- Repeat last step with all of the filters
- Export JSON

That works for me!